# Polymorphism in multilevel inheritance

Tags: c++

The derived class Test2 and Test3 in below code are not virtual type then why are the functions overridden and how to stop that from happening?
P.S ->I am a newbie so the question might be stupid sorry for that.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Test {
public:
  int a, b, c;
  Test(int x, int y, int z) {
    a = x;
    b = y;
    c = z;
  }
  void print() { cout << "a= " << a << "b= " << b << "c= " << c << endl; }
};

class Test2 : public Test {
public:
  int d, e;
  Test2(int a, int b, int c, int x, int y) : Test(a, b, c) {
    d = x;
    e = y;
  }
  virtual void print() { cout << "d= " << d << "e= " << e << endl; }
};

class Test3 : public Test2 {
public:
  int f;
  Test3(int a, int b, int c, int d, int e, int x) : Test2(a, b, c, d, e) {
    f = x;
  }
  void print() { cout << "f= " << f << endl; }
};

class Test4 : public Test3 {
public:
  int g;
  Test4(int a, int b, int c, int d, int e, int f, int x)
      : Test3(a, b, c, d, e, f) {
    g = x;
  }
  void print() { cout << "g= " << g << endl; }
};

int main() {
  Test *test;
  Test2 *test2;
  Test3 *test3;
  Test4 test4(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7);
  test = &test4;
  test2 = &test4;
  test3 = &test4;
  test->print();
  test2->print();
  test3->print();
  test4.print();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you describe how the behavior differs from what you were expecting and on which line?

Comment: `Test2::print` *hides* `Test::print` (and redeclares it to be `virtual`) - all children of `Test2` inherit the function as `virtual`

Comment: @UnholySheep so i can't access print of any class derived directly or indirectly from Test2?

Comment: You could explicitly call them: `test3->Test3::print();`

Comment: `The derived class Test2 and Test3 in below code are not virtual type` What does it mean for a class to be "virtual type"? Anyway, they **do** both have virtual functions called `print()`, so overriding does occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Test2::print` is `virtual` and therefore a call to `print` on a pointer to `Test2` or a pointer to a class that derives from `Test2` will use the runtime type of the object to determine which function to call. In your case the runtime type of the object is `Test4` so it will call `Test4::print`. That is the point of `virtual` functions.

If you want to explicitly call a different version of `print` you can do so, e.g `test3->Test3::print();`